# Pattern greater less than sign

Tags: r, regex

I want to clean special characters from variable.

```
mm = data.frame(rule = c('$X <= 0', '$X > 0 & $X <= 17.5', '> 17.5 & $X <= 197.3', '$X > 197.3'))
mm$ruleclean <- gsub('\\&',' ',gsub('\\s+','',gsub('\\$X', '', mm$rule)))
```

Desired Output:

```
<=0
0 - 17.5
17.5 - 197.3
> 197.3
```

Objective is to convert it into intervals

Comment: Are you intentionally omitting the leading `$X` from the third string?

Comment: It’s not clear by what logic characters are retained and removed, try explaining what you want to achieve … your desired output doesn’t make sense to me.

Comment: @r2evans : Yes, I don't need $X.

Comment: You're going to confuse yourself with nesting those `gsub`s, especially for debugging. You should try splitting them out into separate lines. Also, how are you defining special characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a verbatim attempt, certainly prone to issues. I'm using `magrittr`'s pipe operator `%>%` for clarity of code (along the lines of @camille's comment about nested `gsub`s), though it is not strictly required for function. Also, I changed the first value from `0` to `-1` solely to demonstrate some ambiguity you might have with negative numbers.

```r
mm = data.frame(rule = c('$X <= -1', '$X > 0 & $X <= 17.5', '> 17.5 & $X <= 197.3', '$X > 197.3'))

library(magrittr)
gsub("&", "", mm$rule) %>%
  gsub("(\\s*\\$X\\s*)?<=?\\s*", "..", .) %>%
  gsub("(\\$X\\s*)?>=?\\s*", "", .) %>%
  gsub("^\\.\\.", "<=", .) %>%
  gsub("(-[0-9.]+)", "(\\1)", .) %>%
  gsub("\\.\\.", "-", .) %>%
  gsub("^([0-9.]+)$", ">\\1", .)
# [1] "<=(-1)"     "0-17.5"     "17.5-197.3" ">197.3"
```

(**Edit**: corrected the last string.)

I think one way I'd do this different in the future is not hard-coding the leading `<=` and `>` in the first/last strings, being more robust. Furthermore, I might personally prefer the mathematic nomenclature for closed/open ends, along the lines of `(,-1]` (or `(-Inf,-1]`), `(0,17.5]`, etc, for several reasons: clarity in the meaning, and it is consistent with R's `cut` factor levels.